# uploading data to MySQL with android

Tags: android, mysql

Hi I am currently works in Android project with MySQL db ... I have one database With multiple tables. When I upload data to table1 it is saved, but when I insert data into table2 I show error .. Both table have same Colomns name, i wrote same PHP script with same table name as mention above..Plz post your answers. If somebody have solution.

Comment: could you please post your logcat?

Comment: and please share some code

Comment: Solutions require specifics, and in this case having some sense of what you're doing in terms of code would help considerably. This is like showing up to the mechanic with a car problem, but not bringing the car.